# closing processes using /home in order to move /home to new drive

Tags: home-directory, process, kill, killall

I'm moving my /home from one drive to another new drive. I'm doing it from tty3 as root.

I've used sudo mv '/home' '/old_home' but it says device or resource busy.

I've tried to kill the process accessing files in /home but kill PID and killall [command] don't close the processes

Comment: Try running `lsof | grep /home` to see if any files are open.

Comment: Do you have a home-partition already mounted on `/home`?

Comment: What do you mean by "as root", exactly? since you are using sudo, does that mean you are still actually logged in as a non-root user? or have you enabled root login?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use `sudo fuser --mount --user /home/*` to see the processes, or `sudo lsof +D /home` (see `man fuser;man lsof`), **but**:

The easiest, safest way is to download a Luve USB release, burn it to a USB key, and boot from it. This will guarantee that no process has the former `/home` open. You will be able to manually mount your old partitions to copy from.

This is more complex if you're using encrypted `$HOME` directories.